# Forge viewer markups extension prevent multiple types of tools

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We are programmatically adding a circle and some text while in edit mode which is working great. We want to prevent the user from adding any more shapes to the layer but still allow them to move the circle and text around the canvas. Is there anyway to prevent the canvas from drawing a shape if there is already one of that type in the current layer?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no official config option for only allowing selection/movement, and preventing the creation of additional markups. You would have to reverse-engineer and override some of the event handling methods of the `MarkupsCore` extension object. For example, the `onMouseDown` method looks like this:

```js
proto.onMouseDown = function(event) {
    dismissLmvHudMessage();
    this.callSnapperMouseDown();
    var bounds = this.getBounds();
    var mousePosition = this.getMousePosition();

    if (mousePosition.x >= bounds.x && mousePosition.x <= bounds.x + bounds.width && mousePosition.y >= bounds.y && mousePosition.y <= bounds.y + bounds.height) {
        this.editMode.onMouseDown(event);
    }

    if (!this.editMode.creating && event.target === this.svg) {
        this.selectMarkup(null);
    }
    this.ignoreNextMouseUp = false;
};
```

Her, you could theoretically avoid passing the "mouse down" event to the "edit mode", preventing any new markup from being created.